# shell command wrapper for socat

Tags: shell, socket

I have used the command

```
socat - foo
```

The text I type is sent directly to address foo.
Is there some general-purpose wrapper for stdin (along the lines of `!` from ed) that lets one parse a shell command and then send the command's output to foo?

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can do:

```
ls | socat - foo
```

or:

```
ls | socat -u - foo
```

if you don't expect anything coming back from `foo`.

Or with `socat` spawning `ls`:

```
socat exec:ls foo
```

If you mean you want to run a command while you run

```
socat - foo
```

in a terminal and have the output sent to foo, then within GNU `screen`, you can use: <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd>`:exec .!. ls` which would run `ls` and `screen` will make the output of `ls` come as input as if typed on the keyboard.

Or you could do instead (with GNU `sed`):

```
sed 's/^!//e' | socat - foo
```

And any input that starts with `!`, like `!echo test` would be replaced by  the output of the command after `!`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some general-purpose wrapper for stdin ... that lets one parse a shell command and then send the command's output to foo?

Perhaps this may inspire you:

```
$ echo pwd | sh
/
$ echo pwd | sh | wc
1       1       2
```

sh is a filter. It can read commands on stdin, run them, and emit their output on stdout.